# sqlite alternative for huge data lists?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm currently using sqlite embedded to store relatively big lists of data (starting from 100'000 rows per table). Queries include only:

- paging
- sorting by a field

Amount of data in a row is relatively small. Performance is really bad, especially for the first query, which is critical for my application. All kinds of tunings and pre-caching already tried and reached the practical limit.

Is there any alternative of an embedded data store library which can do these simple queries in a very fast and efficient way? Theres no requirement for it to support sql at all.

Comment: Have you tried splitting up your tables? There's a danger that handling them can then become unwieldy, but in some cases it works, and will obviously offer improved performance if it does.

Comment: Yes, actually splitting them minimized number of rows from millions to hundreds of thousands, which is still very slow :(

Comment: I am thinking about creating a ghost table for every big table containing only "head" of the big set, so I can respond fast for huge data set while precaching next page. But this just builds up another workaround on sqlite :(

Comment: Have you properly indexed your tables? A well placed index can improve performance by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Well, it's not so much a workaround for sqlite as a workaround for all relational databases - sharding is popular even on Oracle. But the issue probably does come up first on sqlite! Whether you can use this depends very much on your query. For example if you regularly do a search by _region_ in a query, then sharding by region makes sense - the `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE region = 'London' AND ...` becomes `SELECT * FROM my_table_london WHERE ...`.

Comment: Also, can you do any snapshotting (also known as "materialised view" on some db architectures)? That is, create a table with the rows from a common query (or subquery) and do periodic query inserts into them. The downside is that your data in the snapshot can get stale, but the upside is that query performance becomes nearly instantaneous.

Comment: sure, I tried all the straightforward things, stop suggesting them please :) The problem with sqlite is huuuge initialisation time which is impossible to solve no matter how you prepare the huuuge rowset of data (it will read everything from disk before handing over control to your program)

Comment: Gah! and I was only trying to help you.</exits>

Answer (score 0):

If it is (predominantly) read-only, consider using memory mapped views of a file.

It will be possible to achieve maximum performance rolling your own indexes.

Obviously it will be also be the most work-intensive and error-prone to roll-your-own.

May I suggest a traditional RDBMS with good indexes or perhaps a newfangled no-SQL style DB that supports your work-load?

Comment: The data is changing, slowly but quite often :( Traditional sql servers like MySQL would fit perfect, but that goes out of scope of an embedded application and will cause lots of extra deployment issues :(   I should look at these nosql dbs though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try lucene.net, it is blazing fast, does not require any installation, supports paging and sorting by fields and much much more.
http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

With Simple Lucene wrapper it is also quite easy to use: http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/SimpleLucene-e28093-Lucenenet-made-easy.aspx

Comment: Lucene doesn't handle very well navigating to a last page of 1 million list very well and it's primary use is full-text search I'm afraid.

Comment: The way it's index is implemented should allow it to page results faster than RDBMS in general case and yes, it is intended for full text search, but that does not prevent from using it as persistence layer (plus if you have millions of rows, I'm pretty sure search should be handfull for you :).